# $\mathrm{Ext}^i(-,A/\mathfrak{m})$ in $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ noetherian regular local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, noetherian, derived-functors, sheaf-cohomology

Dealing with $\mathrm{Ext}^i(\mathcal{F},k(x))$ on a smooth variety over a field $k$, with $\mathcal{F}$ coherent and $k(x)$ skyscraper sheaf of a closed point I foundin a proof that for $i=2,3$ (and hence i guess for $i \geq 2$) it vanishes. I know that it reduces to a question about $\mathrm{Ext}^i(M,A/\mathfrak{m})$ where $M$ is a finitely generated module (i.e. the stalk at $x$ of $\mathcal{F}$) and $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ is a noetherian regular local ring.

How can I prove what I found claimed? Also, do I need all the hypothesis I have or something less is enough? I was not sure whether to approach it directly, or whether to argue something from some exact sequence, such as $0 \rightarrow \mathfrak{m} \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m} \rightarrow 0$ or a locally free resoulution of $M$, but after scribbling something on a piece of paper I did not get far with these ideas...

Comment: If $A$ is the localization of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ at $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $M=A/\mathfrak m$, can you compute those Exts explicitly?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I will try. Even though the question makes me feel I should know the answer!

Comment: @Stefano, well, your question makes me feel you do *not* know the answer :-)

Comment: (To dothe computation you can use the fact that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is a regular sequence generating the maximal ideal in my example, so you can resolve $A/m$ using a Koszul complex)

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments! I guess I found out where my mistake comes from, since I think I messed up some indices in a spectral sequence (the surviving of a thing at page 2 until page infinity brought my question up). Anyway I will think about all these things, since it is pretty evident I don't know much about it. Later I will edit the question so that it makes more sense.